# "Register your site" link in Configuration Checklist leads to broken page

Tags: registration, configuration, online-registration

Just installed CiviCRM in a new wordpress docker container I pulled this morning. Going through the Configuration Checklist, the 4th link from the top leads to a broken page with a "Page not found" error. I verified it does the same thing in the English Demo site.

To reproduce, just open the Demo site, click Administer > Administration Console > Configuration Checklist, and click the "Register your site" link, 4th from the top of that list.

Comment: thx have passed it on to those who can fix it

Comment: https://lab.civicrm.org/marketing/civicrm-website/-/issues/209